# What is the best way to mark or annotate objective-c methods that implement an interface definition?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have several "private" methods in my .m file but only a handful are actually
defined in the matching header file. When using the IDE it is not clear which of the methods are actual api methods. While Java IDE's are quite smart and annotate expose/overridden methods with an Icon in the gutter of the IDE. (typically ItelliJ/Eclipse does a great job here).

I would like to achieve the same clarity in Xcode while using Objective-C.

I have though of using #pramga marks but would rather conform to some best known practice. Any suggestions on what approaches work best.

Comment: All header methods are your own no?

Comment: All headers are my own.

Comment: lol, then I don't understand your question. Personally, I just use a bunch of comments, and know which methods are mine (in the body) from knowing which are apples. Pragma marks seem like over kill to me, if you fold code often (shift,cmd,alt,left) you can see the structure.